# Personal sandbox for deleted favorites

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, bookmarks

If I put a question in my favorites and it is deleted afterwards I lose the link forever.

Can we have a personal per-user sandbox where we can access our Favorites regardless whether any items were deleted for some reason?

10k+ users can't see questions which were permanently deleted by a moderator. Most of this questions are spam, however, some may be of personal value to the user. At least, he will be able to recover the post from his sandbox.

Comment: You can't favorite an answer and 10K users do see deleted favorites, with red background. What is the point in having a link to something you can't access?

Comment: You can access them if you have 10k reputation on the site.

Comment: If you can access deleted questions (10k rep), you are actually able to see them in your favorites as well.

Comment: @poke: yes, but not all. Answers/questions can be deleted permanently and adding them to Favorites won't help.

Comment: @SergeyK. Hard deletions are *very* rare.  It almost never happens.

Comment: Nothing get deleted permanently except very rare cases of DMCA requests. Moderator can't do it, only a dev with direct access to the database. If you can't see a deleted question as 10K user it's a bug.

Comment: @Servy: i've seen at least 2 hard-deleted questions here in 3 years, which were of personal interest to me (10+ upvotes, but off-topic). And I would be happy to have a possibility to recover the answers from that questions.

Comment: @SergeyK. Out of the *millions* of questions asked in those 3 years, on SO alone, that makes it a very low rate of deletion indeed.

Comment: Can you give an example of what such a question would be like?

Comment: @poke: this question was deleted from SO: http://answer.techwikihow.com/517214/does-line-code.html It had ~100+ upvotes and marked as duplicate to a question with much lower number of upvotes. All valuable comments are now lost.

Comment: Yet, I can still [access the original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358122/what-does-this-line-of-c-code-do); and favorite it.

Comment: @poke: oh, great! Thanks for the link! Looks like the issue is now solved.